# Error converting form boost::shared_ptr<T> to std::shared_ptr<T>

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, shared-ptr

I wrote a function template to "convert"/repack a `boost::shared_ptr<T>` to a `std::shared_ptr<T>` and vice versa by following [this proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12605002/3385047). It's working fine unless I have a `boost::shared_pt<T>` and the type of `T` is an abstract class.

What I figured out so far is, that the problem occurs when `boost/shared_ptr.hpp` and `boost/shared_array.hpp` are included together. If only `boost/shared_ptr.hpp` is included it's working when the type of `T` is an abstract class.

I'm using clang 3.3 and boost 1.55.0 . It would be great if someone could tell my why it's not working and how to get it working.

Thanks for your help

Here is a minimal example:

```
//main.cpp

#include <boost/shared_array.hpp> //removing this include and it's working
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <memory>

template<typename SharedPointer> struct Holder {

    SharedPointer p;

    Holder(const SharedPointer &p) : p(p) {}
    Holder(const Holder &other) : p(other.p) {}
    Holder(Holder &&other) : p(std::move(other.p)) {}

    void operator () (...) const {}
};


template<class T>
std::shared_ptr<T> to_std_ptr(const boost::shared_ptr<T> &p)
{
    typedef Holder<std::shared_ptr<T>> H;

    if(H *h = boost::get_deleter<H, T>(p))  // get_deleter seems to cause the problem
    {
        return h->p;
    }
    else
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<T>(p.get(), Holder<boost::shared_ptr<T>>(p));
    }
}
```

Here the code I used to test it:

```
//main.cpp

template<typename T> class Base 
{
public:
    T value;   
    virtual void abstract() = 0;
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

template<typename T> class Derived : public Base<T>
{
public:    
    virtual void abstract() override {}
    virtual ~Derived() {}
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    boost::shared_ptr<Base<int>> ptr{new Derived<int>()};

    // error here
    std::shared_ptr<Base<int>> a = to_std_ptr(ptr);

    // no error here
    std::shared_ptr<Base<int>> b = to_std_ptr(boost::static_pointer_cast<Derived<int>>(ptr));

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the error message(shortened):

```
boost/smart_ptr/shared_array.hpp:111:102: error: array of abstract class type 'Base<int>'
    shared_array( shared_array<Y> const & r, typename boost::detail::sp_enable_if_convertible< Y[], T[] >::type = boost::detail::sp_empty() )

main.cpp:64:40: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::shared_array<Base<int> >' requested here 
    if(H *h = boost::get_deleter<H, T>(p))

main.cpp:86:36: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'to_std_ptr<Base<int> >'requested here
    std::shared_ptr<Base<int>> i = to_std_ptr(ptr);

main.cpp:23:18: note: unimplemented pure virtual method 'abstract' in 'Base'
    virtual void abstract() = 0;
```

What I get from the error message is that the compiler tried to create an array of abstract classes what of course doesn't work. But why is he even trying to do so and what has `boost/sharred_array` to do with that. Is he maybe picking the wrong overload for `boost::get_deleter`?

Comment: Note there's a problem with this approach of conversion, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314967/cohabitation-of-boostshared-ptr-and-stdshared-ptr#comment28669000_12315035

Comment: If you define `BOOST_SP_NO_SP_CONVERTIBLE` before including `shared_array.hpp`, it compiles.

Comment: I was just made aware of this, [but I can't reproduce it](https://ideone.com/1Csbbx). Is this still a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a small example of where the error comes from:

```
struct abstract
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

template<class X, class Y>
struct templ {};

template<class T>
struct bar
{
    template<class U>
    bar(templ<U[], T[]>) {} // (A)
};

int main()
{
    bar<abstract> x;
}
```

It seems even to be illegal to form the type *array of [abstract-type]* in `(A)`, therefore *instantiating* the class template `bar` with the argument `abstract` makes the program ill-formed.

---

The same thing is happening in the background for `shared_array`. But why is `shared_array<Base>` instantiated?

The free function `boost::get_deleter` is overloaded, `shared_array.hpp` adds an overload to the overload set (actually, adds a template):

```
template< class D, class T > D * get_deleter( shared_array<T> const & p );
```

Before overload resolution, even before finding out which functions are viable, function templates need to be instantiated. Instantiating this `get_deleter` template above leads to instantiating `shared_array<Base>`, which leads to the program being ill-formed.

The solution is, not to let the above get instantiated: Don't supply the template parameter `T`, it can't deduce the `T` in `shared_array<T>` from a `shared_ptr<T>`: the two types are unrelated.

Change

```
if(H *h = boost::get_deleter<H, T>(p))
```

to

```
if(H *h = boost::get_deleter<H>(p))
```

and it works.

---

Explanation why letting `T` be deduced works:

When writing a function call where a function template could be meant (looking at the name called), the template parameters have to be set. You can supply them explicitly (inside `<>` as in `get_deleter<H, T>`). If you don't supply all of them explicitly (as in `get_deleter<H>`), the remaining ones have to be deduced from the arguments of the function call.

After all template parameters have been either set explicitly or deduced, their occurrences in the function template are substituted. The error when using `get_deleter<H, Derived>` occurs in this step: the substituted `get_deleter` looks like this:

```
template<> H * get_deleter( shared_array<Derived> const & p );
```

Here, `shared_array<Derived>` needs to be instantiated. But during this instantiation, the error explained above occurs. (Note: it's not in the immediate context of `get_deleter`, therefore SFINAE doesn't apply.)

Now, when you don't explicitly supply the second template parameter, it has to be deduced. And this deduction fails for the function template

```
template< class D, class T > D * get_deleter( shared_array<T> const & p );
```

if you use an argument expression of type `shared_ptr<Derived>`. As *deduction* fails, no instantiation takes place of the function template, and therefore no instantiation of `shared_array<Derived>` (deduction fails = some template parameters could not be set).

Why does deduction fail? The compiler needs to deduce the template parameter `T` inside the function parameter type `shared_array<T> const&` from the argument expression, which is of the type `shared_ptr<Derived>`. But this deduction can only succeed (with few exceptions) when the function parameter type can be made equal to the argument expression type. I.e., it can only succeed if there's some type `X`, such that `shared_array<X>` is the same type as `shared_ptr<Derived>`. But there isn't: the specializations of `shared_ptr` and `shared_array` are unrelated.

Therefore, the template parameter `T` of this `get_deleter` overload cannot be deduced; therefore this function template isn't instantiated, and `shared_array<Derived>` isn't instantiated.

Deduction failure is a special kind of failure (like SFINAE): It doesn't lead to the program being ill-formed (i.e. it doesn't lead to a compilation error). Rather, the function template for which deduction didn't succeed simply doesn't add a function to the overload set. If there are other functions in the overload set, one of those can be called instead.

Another function template

```
template<class D, class T> D * get_deleter( shared_ptr<T> const & p )
```

from `boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp` runs through the same process. However, deduction succeeds here, and a specialization `get_deleter<H, T>` (with the `H` and `T` from `to_std_ptr`) is added to the overload set. It'll later be chosen by overload resolution.

Comment: I realise this explanation might be a bit short. Leave a comment if I shall elaborate.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I changed it to `boost::get_deleter<H>(p)` and it works now. Even if I understand now why the compiler is trying to instantiate `get_deleter` in `shared_array.hpp` I'm not fully aware of why `boost::get_deleter<H>(p)` works.

Comment: @ruediger-H2 I've added an explanation. Hope it helps!

Comment: @ruediger-H2 In short, when explicitly specifying the second template parameter, there's a substitution failure *not* in the immediate context (=> compilation error). When *not* explicitly specifying the second template parameter, there's a *different* failure, a deduction failure, which leads to this function template being "ignored" for this call.

Comment: I was just made aware of this. I don't understand the problem yet, `T` in the conversion function should be `Base`, not `Derived`. https://ideone.com/1Csbbx

Comment: @Fozi Yes, the same issue still exists. The point is that the inclusion of `boost/shared_array.hpp` breaks the compilation of the program. This is still the case with your example. Hope that link works: https://ideone.com/vOi9ud

Comment: Thanks, I see. This looks like a massive bug in `boost::shared_array` though. I'm not a fan of putting in workarounds for unrelated libraries, even in this case. Not sure what to do here, I'll have to give it some thought.

Comment: @Fozi Not really sure if I'd consider that a bug in `boost::shared_array`. The function template `boost::get_deleter` is not supposed to be called with the second template argument specified *explicitly*. In general, most function templates are intended to deduce their arguments. Various issues will happen if you explicitly specify template arguments; usually there's some metaprogramming involved which is not part of the (guaranteed / documented) interface. It's like a hidden parameter.

Comment: Well, I can't say I'm convinced, but the deduction does not seem to break anything and it [seems to be recommended](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/get_deleter), so I'm applying it in the other thread. Thanks from me too for the excellent explanation, your expertise is always appreciated. 